# Why there are no allocations with AnyVal and generics in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, value-type, jmh

I have an unexpected result with a benchmark.

The aim of this benchmark is to illustrate that Scala AnyVal doesn't play well with generics. I've created a type `AnyValId` that extends `AnyVal`.

The expected result is to see allocations with the gc profiler when calling generic methods `contains` or `identity0`.

Can you help me to figure out what happens here ?

Here is the bench

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(value = 1, jvmArgsAppend = Array("-Djmh.stack.lines=3"))
@Threads(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 3, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
class MapBench {
  var set: Set[AnyValId] = _
  var id: AnyValId       = _

  @Setup
  def setup() = {
    set = Set(AnyValId(1))
    id = AnyValId(1)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def _idWith(): AnyValId = identity0(id)

  @Benchmark
  def contains(): Boolean =
    set.contains(id)

  def identity0[T](t: T) = t

}

case class AnyValId(i: Int) extends AnyVal
```

Here are the results

```
[info] Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt   Score    Error   Units
[info] MapBench._idWith                       avgt    3   2,128 ±  2,015   ns/op
[info] MapBench._idWith:·gc.alloc.rate        avgt    3  ≈ 10⁻⁴           MB/sec
[info] MapBench._idWith:·gc.alloc.rate.norm   avgt    3  ≈ 10⁻⁶             B/op
[info] MapBench._idWith:·gc.count             avgt    3     ≈ 0           counts
[info] MapBench.contains                      avgt    3   3,985 ±  0,668   ns/op
[info] MapBench.contains:·gc.alloc.rate       avgt    3  ≈ 10⁻⁴           MB/sec
[info] MapBench.contains:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt    3  ≈ 10⁻⁶             B/op
[info] MapBench.contains:·gc.count            avgt    3     ≈ 0           counts
```

update with further investigation in the REPL

```
scala> case class Id(i: Int)
class Id

scala> Set(Id(1))
val res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Id] = Set(Id(1))

scala> def f = res3.contains(Id(2))
def f: Boolean

:javap f
```

Here is the bytecode, as contains is parameterized on `Id`, it seems that an instance of `Id` is required to call it. Hence the `new` instruction in bytecode. **So the behavior seems different in the REPL and in a JMH benchmark.**

```
public boolean f();
  descriptor: ()Z
  flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=5, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #29                 // Method $line32$$read$$iw$$$outer:()L$line32/$read;
       4: invokevirtual #33                 // Method $line32/$read.$line30$read:()L$line30/$read;
       7: invokevirtual #36                 // Method $line30/$read.$iw:()L$line30/$read$$iw;
      10: invokevirtual #40                 // Method $line30/$read$$iw.res3:()Lscala/collection/immutable/Set;
      13: new           #14                 // class $line29/$read$$iw$Id
      16: dup
      17: getstatic     #46                 // Field $line29/$read$.MODULE$:L$line29/$read$;
      20: invokevirtual #50                 // Method $line29/$read$.INSTANCE:()L$line29/$read;
      23: invokevirtual #53                 // Method $line29/$read.$iw:()L$line29/$read$$iw;
      26: iconst_2
      27: invokespecial #57                 // Method $line29/$read$$iw$Id."<init>":(L$line29/$read$$iw;I)V
      30: invokeinterface #63,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/immutable/Set.contains:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      35: ireturn
    LineNumberTable:
      line 1: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      36     0  this   L$line32/$read$$iw;
```

Comment: I would first look at the byte code - is it simplified by compiler? Even when that's not the case JIT might optimize it. You need to dig in.

Comment: You know, it's hard to tell anything if you have no comparison. You should make the same benchmark for raw Int and establish baseline.

Comment: Without looking at the bytecode, my suspicion is that the allocation occurs in `setup`: `Set(AnyValId(1))` requires boxing and, since `AnyValId` is `final` and immutable (by virtue of extending `AnyVal`, that `Int` is also an `AnyVal` may also be relevant), the same boxed value can be used.  It might be useful to try with a `String` as the wrapped type.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've understand what happens. I made 2 mistakes in this benchmark

1. The `Set` contains only one element, so a very optimized implementation is used `Set$Set1` with a `contains` method than rely only on `equals` and not `hashCode`. So, I've fixed the setup to use a longer Set.
2. Hence, `hashCode` is called. It boxes the int by calling `Integer.valueOf`. Nevertheless, this method uses a cache internally. So because the integer is in the range [-127, 128], there is no allocation.

One more time, this disclaimer is really relevant.

> REMEMBER: The numbers below are just data. To gain reusable insights,
> you need to follow up on why the numbers are the way they are.

[image]